# Is there any fastest method to update edmx?

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Sqlserver 2008 . I want to generate or update edmx. it take 8-15 minute to generate edmx. is there is any tool to create edmx fast?

Answer (score 0):

I have a tool that works with VS2008, VS2010, VS2012, and VS2013, that can do both full and incremental updates of EDMX files. It doesn't work with VS2015 though, as development has been on ice for a while, and VS2015 don't support the same integration interfaces as previous versions of Visual Studio.

You can download it from https://huagati.com/edmxtools/ (free nowadays), and there's a screencast showing the functionality I think you are looking for at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=doqYOlcEAZM

Answer (score -1):

I don't know any way to generate EDMX model besides the "Update Model from database" approach. However, from my own experience, if your model is too big, you have 2 options:

1. Split your current model into several parts (Microsoft recommends 50 entities per model); or
2. Use Code-First instead of EDMX

Hope it helps!

Comment: i have more than 500+ tables in databse.

Comment: I believe Code-First is the best approach, or at least you have to use several data models (50 tables per model)